# Erlang lists:keyfind/3 not working as expected

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

What's wrong with the following code fragment?

```
> A = [{X, 1} || X <- lists:seq(1,5)].
> lists:keyfind({3,1}, 1, A).
false
```

Why is the function returning false? It should ideally return {3,1}.

Comment: Why did you expect it to return `{3,1}`? `lists:keyfind/3` only searches the Nth (in this case 1) item of each tuple in the list, not the whole thing. Did you mean to do `lists:keyfind(3, 1, A).`?

Comment: i think i don't properly understand the second argument of this function. What does this `N` mean? and what if i want to match `{3,1}` instead of just `3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lists:keyfind/3` searches a list of tuples by comparing the `N`th value of each tuple against the given value. Your code is searching for a tuple whose first element is `{3, 1}`, which doesn't exist in your list. To search for tuples whose first element is `3`, you can do `lists:keyfind(3, 1, A).`:

```
1> A = [{X, 1} || X <- lists:seq(1,5)].
[{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1}]
2> lists:keyfind({3,1}, 1, A).
false
3> lists:keyfind(3, 1, A).
{3,1}
```

If you want to find an exact value, you can use `lists:member/2` to check if it exists:

```
4> lists:member({3,1}, A).
true
```